# javascript text overlay HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, overlay

I am tyring to get the text overlay effect like here http://ryun.github.io/HCaptions/
on this template : http://html5up.net/parallelism/
Multiple javascripts on single page is trouble.

this particular section needs some repair, I suppose...

```
            <!--- Begin Content --->
        <div id="main">                     
            <!--- Begin Reel Markup --->
            <div id="reel">                             
                    <!-- Thumb Items -->
                    <article class="item thumb" data-width="282">                              
                            <a href="#myToggle" data-target="#myToggle" class="panel">
                            <img src="images/thumb/1.jpg" />
                            </a>
                         <div id="myToggle" class="cap-overlay hide">
                             <h5>Thumb Title</h5>                                
                            <div class="content">
                                Name: name.jpg<br />
                                Details: Details Text<br />
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button small"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a> 
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button small"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                                                                                        
                    </article>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Any solution ? or Any alternative ?

PS : I have tried almost every possible popular plugin but no luck

Comment: Where's **your** code?

Comment: Why don't you just use that JS you linked? (HCaptions)

Comment: Your not going to get far if you think that a **plugin** is the only way to go, and if you mean the captions then you would be **silly** to use a plugin for that

Comment: @David : Individually both the scripts are working perfectly fine.. Howver when I try to get the layover effect on the thumbnails in the template, I screw everything up

Comment: @Connor : I hav tried almost everypopular plugin out there on the first 7 pages of google search, the CSS hover effect isin't that wow...

Comment: @Mike : both the links I pasted are open sources under MIT Licenses...

Comment: Beggers can't be choosers

Comment: @user2581713 So? You say they don't work when **you** combine them. Unless you show what **you** have done, nobody can help.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a quick example I just baked with pure `CSS`

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="caption">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa pariatur repellat ad reprehenderit est consequatur saepe reiciendis earum quasi alias magni autem suscipit a blanditiis nam eius explicabo deleniti quam!
    </div>
    <img src="http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/parallelism/images/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caption{
    position:absolute;
    top:-500px; left:0; right:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:white;
    font-family:arial;
    padding:30px;
    text-align:justify;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.box{
    width:383px;
    height:212px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.box:hover .caption{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BLEPL/1/)

If you added all the correct vendor prefixes this would be cross browser and mostly cross browser ( with transitions )

If you like icing on your cake you could find some here http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67

Comment: You don't seem to be getting much magical luck today do you.... it's pure css as you can see in the fiddle